# Chrome websocket connection delay

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I have a weird problem with websockets and chrome (22.0.1229.79m) (I haven't coded authentication for other browsers yet so I cant test them).  It seems like if I reload chrome 3 times, there will be a huge delay in connecting to my websocket server.  The server is not delaying the connection, I tested this by connecting to it with another PC while chrome was delaying and it connected perfectly.

Is there anyway to fix this?  This is a problem when I am switching servers receiving data.  It will halt, and delay.  This is really bad for user experience.  I would assume this is strictly related to the chrome browser not closing the socket...

Comment: I have seen this problem too on some network configurations. It take like 10-15 seconds for the user to connect to the websockets server - and in firefox it is almost instant

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? I just had an issue with websockets taking ~ 1 minute to connect on Chrome, but no delay on Firefox. I hated for a while. Went here. Then realized that I had some extensions. (Disabling 'JetBrains Chrome Extension 0.3.11' helped.)

Comment: I had the same issue. ws connection from chrome to 127.0.0.1:8081 was taking more than 3 seconds; My server was a self written c++ websocket server so I could see the precise 3+ sec delay when the accept() call would yield. Furthermore, a direct telnet from console to the ws server (localhost:8081) would yield immediately as one would expect. So there was definitely something that the browser was doing. Turned out, I had few chrome extensions installed (adblocker, skype). Disabling all of them brought down the delay considerably.

Answer (score 3):

I have also seen this delay when creating multiple WebSocket connections from the same browser tab in Chrome within a short period of time. I believe this is to address a potential security issue with WebSockets which would allow a browser to be hijacked to do port scanning inside a network. By limiting the number of WebSocket connections that can happen within a given amount of time, you greatly limit the utility of a browser as a remote port scanner. In addition, the amount of information that is returned by onclose and onerror is intentionally limited for the same reasons.

Comment: Is Chrome the only one who does this?  Firefox follows their own websocket protocol, maybe thats why it doesnt seem to affect firefox browsers.  I guess I have to switch my target audience to firefox, and shy away from my users using chrome ...  ( since itll be slow and have delayed connections )

Comment: How many connections are you making per page? Firefox and Chrome both follow the W3C spec with regards to limiting the amount of information exposed by the error and close events. I suspect that Firefox will tighten up limits on how many simultaneous connections that can be made, especially if somebody exploits the issue on Firefox.

Comment: If you are seeing slow data transfer as you mention in another comment then this is probably not a specific Chrome issue. I see no such issues. Only when I try and create multiple connections in a short period of time do I see delayed connections.

Comment: Well, I am making a connection to a proxy server that gets server details (which server has room for the user).  That connection is closed as soon as it comes back with the server details.  I then connect to the lobby server, and then when/if they create/join games do they make another connection to a game server.  Thats 3+ connections within a short period of time.  Once connected to the lobby, they dont disconnect from that (unless they log off).